# Select textbox value using jquery , modifications in selector syntax

Tags: jquery, syntax

I want to select the value of a textbox with name : studentid[1] , using this jquery code :

```
var id = 1;
var a = $("input[type='text'][name='studentid\["+id+"\]").val();
```

It yields the output as 'undefined' in the alert box . Is my syntax correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left off the closing single quote and closing square bracket. Here's the corrected version complete with double backslashes where appropriate:

```
var a = $("input[type='text'][name='studentid\\["+id+"\\]']").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj83a/)

```
var id = 1;
var a = $("input[type=text][name=studentid["+id+"]]").val(); 
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using two backslashes instead.  According to jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two backslashes: \.

Answer (score 1):

The `[` and `]` needs 2 backslashes to escape them, also you're missing a closing `]` for the attribute selector.

```
var id = 1;
var a = $("input[type='text'][name='studentid\\["+id+"\\]']").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are a couple of syntax errors there. You forgot to insert trailing bracket and a quote. Moreover, there is no special need in escaping brackets. This code works fine:

```
$(":text[name='studentid[" + id + "]']").val();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jW2MR/

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/J5jN8/

Answer (score 1):

```
var id =1;
$('input[type=text][name="A['+ id +']"]');
```